# How to delete entire row except column A in VBA loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to highlight the entire row grey if the value in column A begins with "ABC" as well as delete everything right of that cell. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
Dim DataRange As Range
Set DataRange = Range("A1:U" & LastRow)

Set MyRange = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

For Each Cell In MyRange
If UCase(Left(Cell.Value, 3)) = "ABC" Then
    Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 15


Else


End If
Next
```

Comment: You could try `Range("B" & Cell.Row & ":U" & Cell.Row).Delete`

Answer (score 1):

Here is pretty straightforward approach:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim row As Long
Dim temp As String

' insert your sheet name here
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("your sheet name")

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' you can change the starting row, right now its 1
    For row = 1 To lastRow

        ' store whats in col A in a temporary variable
        temp = Trim(CStr(.Range("A" & row).Value))

        ' if col A isn't 'ABC' clear & grey entire row
        If UCase(Left(.Range("A" & row).Value), 3) <> "ABC" Then

            .Rows(row).ClearContents
            .Rows(row).Interior.ColorIndex = 15

            ' place temp variable value back in col A and make interior No Fill
            .Range("A" & row).Value = temp
            .Range("A" & row).Interior.ColorIndex = 0

        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: OP says " if the value in column A begins with "ABC" so test should be `If UCase(Left$(Range("A" & row).Value), 3) = "ABC" Then` .  Trimming may or may not be desired.  Case insensitivite as per OP.'s code.  Might be worth mentioning `.ClearContents` leaves (other) formatting in place, alternative is to use `.Clear`

Comment: @chrisneilsen thank you I overlooked the "begins with" part of the OP's question

Comment: Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example; you stated "clear everything to the right" so I added offset to clear the contents of the cells not in column A.

```
Dim x As Long

For x = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If UCase(Left(Cells(x, 1).Value, 3)) = "ABC" Then
        Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        Range(Cells(x, 1).Offset(, 1), Cells(x, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).ClearContents
    End If
Next x
```